# PHP7 Rename all files in directory within iterator (windows 10) 64-bit XAMPP

Tags: php, oop, iterator, rename, file-rename

I need to rename all the songs to integer (numbers) with the following php code, but it shows an error:

```
Warning: rename(abc.mp3,2.4): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in D:\xampp\htdocs\hta\file_renames.php on line 14
```

command PATHINFO_EXTENSION is also not working here?
i am using windows 10 with xampp (php7)

```
<?php $total = 0;
$dir = "songs/";
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileInfo) {
if(!$fileInfo->isDot()){
    $total +=1;
    $file = $fileInfo->getFilename();
    rename($file,$total.'.'.PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}
}
echo('Total files: '.$total);
?>
```

how to rename my all .mp3 files to a number.mp3 file? within loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the complete path (can be relative) to `rename`. Regarding the `PATHINFO_EXTENSION`, you are simply misusing it. Here is the fixed code:

```
<?php
$total = 0;
$dir = "songs/";
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileInfo) {
    if(!$fileInfo->isDot()){
        $total +=1;
        $file = $dir.$fileInfo->getFilename();
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $newFile = $dir.$total.'.'.$ext;
        rename($file, $newFile);
    }
}
echo('Total files: '.$total);
?>
```